# Embed YouTube video on category description

Tags: taxonomy, embed, youtube, categories

I would like to embed a **YouTube video** on my category description pages.

When I pasted the URL or embed code in the editor, I see the video. But on the page itself it just shows the code.

Is there a way to enable YouTube embedding for category (taxonomy) pages?

Comment: How does your theme print the description?

Comment: When I add the Youtube URL, the video shows in the editor, but on the page, it just shows the URL. https://lucidmanager.org/perspectives-on-marketing/

Comment: I'm in the same situation, but I guess Wordpress don't admit codes on category description, what I think it's an error.

Comment: As Krzysiek said it's to do with the way your theme and template render the category description, and not necessarily WordPress's fault. It should be fixable.